# build multiple docker image with kaniko and push to same project in gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-multi-stage-build, kaniko

I am have a single multistage Dockerfile and I am build two images as part of the build. Kaniko fails on the image name which is different from the gitlab project name. I can see that in the logs that Kaniko is trying to look for a project name with the image name, which is non-existent. (only frontend

```
error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: checking push permission for "gitlab.xxx.de:8085/projs/devs/frontend-ecomm:v38.3-54c2e0d7": POST https://gitlab.xxx.de:8085/v2/projs/devs/frontend-ecomm/blobs/uploads/: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:projs/devs/frontend-ecomm Type:repository] map[Action:push Class: Name:projs/devs/frontend-ecomm Type:repository]]
```

`https://gitlab.xxx.de:8085/v2/projs/devs/frontend-ecomm/` is not in the gitlab, but just this!!!
`https://gitlab.xxx.de:8085/v2/projs/devs/frontend/`
Is there any way I can tell Kaniko to use the same project's container registry to upload these images ?

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to use subfolders under the main project name on the docker image name and push the second image.

`https://gitlab.xxx.de:8085/v2/projs/devs/frontend/ecomm/frontend-ecomm`